# progress loading bar not working in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have my custom loading bar when i call some ajax method , it works perfectly in firefox

my code is like this.
**html**:

```
<div id="loading_dim" >
     <div></div>
</div>
```

**css** :

```
 #loading_dim {
      position: fixed;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      background: url('/../img/glass.png');
      display: none; 
 }
 #loading_dim > div {
      position: fixed;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      background: url('/../img/processing.gif') center center no-repeat;
 }
```

**JAVASCRIPT** :

```
 $('#loading_dim').show();
```

Ajax code ......

```
 $('#loading_dim').hide();
```

I also tried other ways  like jquery `.css('display','block')` and javascript  `document.getelementbyid(elementID).style.display='block';` 
All working in firefox but not in chrome or IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#loading_dim > div {
    position: fixed;
    display: none; 
}
</style>
<div id="loading_dim" >
     <div>Loading</div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div>
<input type=button onclick="showF()" value="Show">
<input type=button onclick="hideF()" value="Hide">
</div>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function showF(){
    $("#loading_dim").find("div").show("slow");
}

function hideF(){
    $("#loading_dim").find("div").hide("slow");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `$('#loading_dim').hide();` in success method.
if can't change ajax call like this

```
function(){
 $.ajax({
 url: 'your url',
 type: 'POST',
 data: {},
 async: false,
 success: function() {}
});
```